# How to dissolve cat hair without effecting fabric?

Tags: solutions, solubility, solvents

I am wondering if it is possible to create some sort of a solution that will dissolve cat hair (or dog hair), but, is not harmful to the surrounding fabric? I am picturing a solution you would soak a cat hair covered towel in that will dissolve the hair but leave the towel unharmed. Or, perhaps in a spray bottle that can be sprayed on dog hair covered car cushions, will dissolve the hair but be able to evaporate and not damage the cushions. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm afraid chemistry is of no help here. Hair are **more** durable than most kinds of fabric.

Comment: Probably a biological agent, e.g. an enzyme or protein mixture. That has a better chance of degrading or decomposing keratin than even strong acid etc.

But it would have to have a specific, targeted mechanism; I don't know of such a substance

Comment: I guess experienced pet owners choose their clothing and upholstery so as to match their cat's color (or the other way around).

Answer (score 3):

No, it most likely isn't. Hair and general "fabric" - which might even be animal hair (wool) share too many properties for this to be possible.

If you specify further, there are possibly certain **combinations** of cat hair and specific fabrics that might have properties that allows for this - but the number of possible combinations is as you may imagine, high.

PS: The opposite is easier - acetone could remove most synthetic polymer fabrics while leaving the cat hair, but I suspect it would not help you.

Answer (score 0):

To get pet hair off of couches or other upholstery, use a clean, dry kitchen sponge. Just run it slowly across the couch and the fur will cling to it